# Add up the value of each row and apply in the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, cursor

I have Table A.

```
Table A
| Date        | Tenor    | CCY | Rate |
| --------    | -------- | --- | ---  |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 3 Month  | USD | 500  |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 4 Month  | USD | 300  |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 5 Month  | USD | 700  |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 6 Month  | USD | 400  |
```

I want to add up each row value in the rate column and put the result in the next row and then insert it into Table B. For example we add up the rates of 500 and 300 and put the result in Table B, which is 800.

```
Table B (expected result)
| Date        | Tenor    | CCY | Rate  |
| --------    | -------- | --- | ---   |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 3        | USD | 500   |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 4        | USD | 800   |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 5        | USD | 1000  |
| 17-Jun-2023 | 6        | USD | 1100  |
```

Can you help with the query? I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Does table B already exist? If yes, is it still empty? Do you really want to do inserts at all or is "table B" just a query result?

Comment: table B already exist but still empty and i want insert the result to table B

Comment: Which column defines the order of the rows (which row is `next`)?

Comment: the first row in table A will be the same as the first column in table B, the second row in table B in the rate column is the sum of the first and second rows in the Rate column

Comment: That's clear. The question is how do you know which row is the "first" one, which is the "second" one etc. Keep in mind that by default there is no order of rows and they can appear in any order the RDBMS decides to show them. So do you have an id column or any other column which indicates the order and allows to use ORDER BY?

Comment: @Mugiwara, a windowed `SUM` is an option (`... SUM(Rate) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Tenor ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) ...`), but you need to define which column(s) define the order of the rows (a combination of `Date` and `Tenor` in the example).

Comment: @Mugiwara It seems you're after something like https://dbfiddle.uk/LRPK5Kua, the important question is how to sort/group, as already said. You have likely shown a very small part of the entire table only, so you need to be sure about that to avoid incorrect inserts when working on the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `LAG` with `PARTITION` and `ORDER`.

As mentioned in comments above, the exact way how to sort and group is unclear. But I assume you will be able to modify this if necessary.

According to your sample data, it seems to me you want to set `PARTITION BY date` to "reset" the rate when the date changes. And you want to `ORDER BY date, tenor`.

So the complete query to fetch the data you want to insert will be:

```
SELECT
  Date, Tenor, CCY, Rate,
  Rate + 
  LAG(Rate,1,0) 
    OVER (
     PARTITION BY date 
     ORDER BY Date, Tenor) AS RateToInsert
FROM A;
```

Note: The column `Rate` in this query will not be part of the insert command, I just added it to better check if the `RateToInsert` will be calculated correctly.

This will be the entire insert command based on above query:

```
INSERT INTO B 
  (Date, Tenor, CCY, Rate)
SELECT
  Date, Tenor, CCY,
  Rate + 
  LAG(Rate,1,0) 
    OVER (
     PARTITION BY date 
     ORDER BY Date, Tenor)
FROM A;
```

See this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YengFYin).

It is based on your sample data, but extended by rows having other dates to show how it works. You can see there first the result of the query and then the table B with the inserted rows.

Answer (score 2):

A windowed `SUM()` with the appropriate `OVER` clause is an option, but you need to define which column(s) define the order of the rows (`Date` and `Tenor` in the example):

```
INSERT INTO TableB 
   (Date, Tenor, CCY, Rate)
SELECT 
   Date, Tenor, CCY, 
   SUM(Rate) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Tenor ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM TableA
```

It's not clear from the question how do you group and order the rows, but you can easily adjust the `OVER` clause with the approapriate `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`. Also, using `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` you may change the number of calculated rows.

```
INSERT INTO TableB 
   (Date, Tenor, CCY, Rate)
SELECT 
   Date, Tenor, CCY, 
   SUM(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Tenor ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM TableA
```